# Why does my fan speed go to maximum when changing to intel in nvidia prime?

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, intel, fan

I bought a Medion Erazer P6661 laptop. This laptop has an intel skylake i7 cpu and an Nvidia GTX 950m graphics card. I've installed Ubuntu 16.04, my kernel version is 4.8.0-39-generic.

I have installed the nvidia-375 graphics driver by adding the ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa ppa and using the additional drivers control panel. I've used this website to find out which version is recommended for my Nvidia card https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx.

My problem arises when using nvidia-prime to change to the intel profile, I do this using the NVIDIA X server Settings panel. When logging out and logging back in (this is necessary to complete the switch), after about a minute the fan speed goes to its maximum speed.

In order to change the fan speed  back to normal I have to switch back to the nvidia prime profile and completely shut down my system, it needs to completely shut down because when rebooting the fan stays at maximum.

the output of `lm_sensors` is this:

```
pch_skylake-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +28.0°C  

acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +29.0°C  (crit = +98.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +28.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:         +27.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:         +28.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

When running `glxgears -info` I can verify the intel graphics are working, as far as I can tell the only issue with the intel profile is the fan speed.

```
GL_RENDERER   = Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 520 (Skylake GT2) 
GL_VERSION    = 3.0 Mesa 12.0.6
GL_VENDOR     = Intel Open Source Technology Center
```

To verify that the nvidia card is powered down I run the command `cat /proc/acpi/bbswitch` which results in `0000:01:00.0 OFF`

When running `glxgears -info` when the nvidia profile is active I get the following

```
GL_RENDERER   = GeForce GTX 950M/PCIe/SSE2
GL_VERSION    = 4.5.0 NVIDIA 375.39
GL_VENDOR     = NVIDIA Corporation
```

The laptop works fine when only using the nvidia profile but it drains the battery quite fast, therefore I'm hoping someone knows how to fix this problem.

Comment: Any news? I have the same problem.

Comment: @Glats Hello, I've solved the problem by now, please look at my posted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my own problem by trial and error.

I believe this is a matter of having the right nvidia driver and kernel combination.

I currently have the following nvidia drivers and ubuntu kernel:

```
4.10.0-041000-generic
nvidia driver 375.39
```

What I did was manually install every stable kernel version from http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/ that was higher than the standard version. For every kernel version that still had the problem I tried every available nvidia driver in the "additional drivers" dialog, note that I added the ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa so at the time I could choose between 364, 371, 375.